# Why does a specific windows batch parameter cause a crash?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Contents of test.bat are:

```
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set param1=%~1
echo %param1%
```

Can someone explain why `test.bat "^^!^^^&^^^^"` makes the cmd window crash but `test.bat "^^^&^^^^"` has an expected result of setting `&^` to variable param1?

I can do `test.bat "pass^^!word"` and I get the expected result of pass!word.

Update: `test.bat "^^!^^^^^&^^^^^^^^"` works. But I'm not completely sure why. This gets interpreted to `set param1=^!^^&^^^^`. Why does ^ need ^^^ in front of it?

Comment: Probably because when you `EnableDelayedExpansion`, the `!` has a special meaning and you need to escape it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got many problems, as the special characters will be evaluated mulitple times in your case.

First in the `set` command, the special character phase will reduce your string `"^^!^^^&^^^^"` to
`^!^&^^`
But as delayed expansion is enabled and your string contains an exclamation mark,
another phase will be enabled to reduce the carets again to.
`!&^`

At this point `param1` contains `!&^`, you can test it with `set param1`

But as you try to echo the value with `echo %param1%` another expansion will be executed.
And now you get a problem, as `%param1%` will expand to `!&^`,
The exclamation mark will be removed, as the second exlamation mark is missing for expanding a variable,
the ampersand will be treated as *new command separator* and
the ending caret will be treated as multiline character.
`echo !   &  ^<next line>`

It's much safer to use the delayed expansion here, as this never change the content, as this phase is the last one of the parser.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set param1=%~1
set param1
echo !param1!
```

And all these explanations can be found at [How does CMD.EXE parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/463115)

Answer (score 1):

It is because the escape character for the Windows shell is ^, so:

"^^!^^^^^&^^^^^^^^"

Each ^^ becomes ^

Each ^& becomes &

So finally you will get:

"^!^^&^^^^"

Comment: No he will not get `"^!^^&^^^^"`, the quotes are removed by the tilde in `%~1` and the more carets will be removed by the exlamation mark.

Comment: but only if he uses "EnableDelayedExpansion",... I think..?? yes/no?

Comment: Yes, only if EnabledDelayedExpansion AND at least one exclamation mark is anywhere on the line, but then the carets are evaluated outside and inside of quotes.  `echo "^^^^" ^^^^ x!` results to `"^^" ^ x`